# Use store variables in checkout agreement links

Tags: checkout, variables

Does anyone know the way to access the store variables in checkout agreement links? I want to use something like:

```
I confirm that I read the <a href="{{store url='agb'}}">terms and conditions</a>
```

but the store variable doesn't get processed.

Thank you for your ideas on this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to edit the template `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/checkout/onepage/agreements.phtml` and replace this

```
<?php if ($_a->getIsHtml()):?>
    <?php echo $_a->getContent() ?>
```

With

```
<?php $filter = Mage::helper('cms')->getPageTemplateProcessor();?>
<?php if ($_a->getIsHtml()):?>
    <?php echo $filter->filter($_a->getContent()) ?>
```

there is no need to change the `else` branch since you cannot use links if the agreement is not of type HTML.